# Paraphrase evaluation corpora

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, corpus

Is there a corpus other than MSRPC (Microsoft Research Paraphrase Corpus) for evaluating Paraphrase recognition approaches? I'm using MSRPC but I'm in need of other corpora for evaluating my approach.

Comment: Try asking your question on http://metaoptimize.com/qa/ as well. You might get a better response.

Answer (score 1):

There's also Twitter Paraphrase Corpus:
       http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2015/task1/

You can email the organizers to ask for the data.

Comment: This is a link-only answer; please document any code or documentation here since links can change overtime, making this answer irrelevant.